# Heroku - git push

Tags: heroku

Can anyone please explain what's wrong with these?

```
mhsjaber:~/workspace/newsite (master) $ heroku keys:add
? Which SSH key would you like to upload? /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub SSH key... done

mhsjaber:~/workspace/newsite (master) $ heroku create
Creating app... done, ⬢ ancient-island-20017
https://ancient-island-20017.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/ancient-island-20017.git

mhsjaber:~/workspace/newsite (master) $ git push heroku
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: was my answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add something first to push to heroku server. As your repository is already created on heroku thus, you have to add your app on it, in order to do that follow below steps.

(1) `heroku login`

(2) `git init`

(3) `git add .`

(4) `git commit -am "comment"`

(5) `git push heroku master`

in your case you were confusing heroku by not adding master in your git push command.